# UIButton not responding

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview, uibutton

I have a series of views which, in an editing mode, add UIButtons in order to trigger an editing mode for their contents.

The problem I have is because I have several of these views, and their frames are overlapping, causing any UIButtons that are below another view to be masked by the view above it, causing it not to respond.

I'm thinking that I may have to create a new view in which all the buttons are added but I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't an easier, more direct way to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the `exclusiveTouch` property is set to NO.  NO is the default, though.

The 'userInteractionEnabled` property can also "turn off" touch handlers for a given view.  I believe this also affects its subviews though... you would have to check.

lastly, you can override the touch handlers, `touchesBegan:withEvent:` etc., to pass their touch events to the views below it.  (this is much more work however)

In practice, a top level view that holds the buttons seems like the most practical thing to do, especially if you don't have to worry about things moving around underneath you.

Answer (score 3):

A couple things to consider:

- Use -bringSubviewToFront: to, well, bring a subview to the front.
- Try to design your app so that views don't overlap where you want to have your buttons.

Comment: So there's no easy means of getting a UIView to act transparently or anything? i.e. Allow views underneath to receive touch events?

Comment: +1, solved my 'not thinking on a Sunday morning' problem... : D